# What is the parallel function in 2017a MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing, task-parallel-library, matlab-guide, parallels

(D:\Users\Dacy\Desktop\parallel.png)

When using the command`matlabpool open local 4`, then it remind me Undefined function or variable 'matlabpool'.

Is there a change for parallel function?

Comment: You might want to know, that your attempt to included a local disk file does not work this way -- use a link to pastebin or other online-URL resource and such image can be posted here.

Answer (score 6):

`matlabpool` was removed in MATLAB 2016a according to the [Parallel Computing Toolbox Release Notes](https://www.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/release-notes.html?searchHighlight=matlabpool). Use [`parpool`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/parpool.html?searchHighlight=parpool&s_tid=doc_srchtitle) instead.

```
parpool('local',4);
```

Comment: Thanks! 
But I have another question. If there are  communication between datas is the using of  parpool function still reasonable ? In other words，could the parpool function be used in 
Independent process only?

Comment: I don't know what "communication between datas" means, but as far as I know `parpool` opens a pool of workers the same as `matlabpool` used to.